# Overcoming UI blocks when updating ng-repeat data

Tags: angularjs

So yes, apparently it is possible to have long grid with lots of rows built with angular. But then a problem comes with data updates.

You see if I just get all (let's say 10 000 rows) and render them in my grid - that works. It just takes a few seconds initially. And

a) I don't have all the date up front
b) I need the grid to be responsive immediately.

I can just do that with throwing let's say only 100 rows at the beginning, and then slowly update data as it becomes available. And that turns out to be the problem. Everytime you push new rows into `$scope.data` - it blocks UI. So I need to be smart about these updates.

- Maybe I should set an interval and update the data only every few seconds? *That seems to be not working*
- Maybe I should somehow watch for mouse movements and once it stops moving - start/resume adding rows, once mouse-movement detected seize adding rows and wait for another chance? - *What if user never stops moving the mouse? (say some sort of a psycho)*
- Experimenting with _.throtle and _.debounce didn't get me anywhere.

  You guys have any ideas?

UPD: here's a crazy one: what if? instead of waiting till angular updates the DOM, create entire DOM structure in memory, right before the digest cycle (with no data) and then insert that HTML chunk (that would be faster, right?) And after that let angular do its magic, data should appear. Would that work?

Comment: Could you show the code for pushing new rows into $scope.data?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to run into performance issues when something changes even if you can get all those rows rendered to the DOM. And your user probably isn't going to scroll through 10000 rows anyway. I would just use pagination. e.g.:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | startFrom:currentPage*itemsPerPage | limitTo:itemsPerPage"></div>
```

If you really want to have everything on one page you could load the rows as the user scrolls. If you are interested in that solution checkout http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/

Comment: I don't want pagination. I'm using ux-angularjs-datagrid. It can handle huge number of rows

Answer (score 0):

One of the things I've noticed that I stupidly used to ignore - the container has to have fixed height. That significantly makes updates faster. Although technically it doesn't solve the problem entirely